# Is it possible to use 'bundle exec' functionality from code?

Tags: ruby, rspec, bundler

I'm building a web interface to a few tools and I'd like to be able to run commands or gems within a Bundler context, like the 'bundle exec' command does, except from within my code.

So usually, I'd write on the command line:

```
bundle exec rspec
```

Is there a way I can achieve the same thing, but programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run some ruby with bundled gems you can just require "bundler/setup":

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'rspec' # loads the version specified in Gemfile
```

Comment: So if I set $BUNDLE_GEMFILE as the tools Gemfile (like with bundlers --binstubs option), this will run it in that context?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap shell commands in backticks (`) in Ruby.

```
def run_specs
    `bundle exec rspec | grep foo`
end
```